# Pivot table filtering with 2 cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to build a pivot table in Excel 2016 which would have filter**s** linked to other Excel cells, so that instead of adjusting filters manually, they are linked to cell values (values change based on INDEX-MATCH formula).

Plenty of sources online and I was able to locate a working code. The challange is that I have 2 separate filters (I wouldn't want to combine data to keep filters at 1).

This works fine, however just for one cell and one filter:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Worksheets(1).Range("I6:I7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim pivot_item As PivotItem
Dim NewCat As String
Dim test_val As String

'Here you amend to suit your data
Set pt = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Brand")
NewCat = Worksheets(1).Range("I6").Value

'Here is the test if the input field exists
test_val = NewCat
For Each pivot_item In pt.PivotFields("Brand").PivotItems
    If pivot_item.Name = test_val Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next pivot_item
On Error Resume Next

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With
End Sub
```

There is another PivotField with a filter `"Type"` which I'm trying to link to Range `"H6"`. I copied the adjusted code right under this (also as WorkSheet property) with adjusted Ranges and Fields. The values should have been correct as this code also worked - alone.

Given that I was not allowed to have two codes with same name, I renamed the other as **2**, which I'm not sure is correct. I did not get any error message, however the second code is not working. I will get results when changing cell "I6" value, however no effect with "H6".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange2(ByVal Target As Range)
```

How could I get both of those filters linked to their separate cells (at the same time)? Or does this all have to work within the same code?

Having it working by just changing cell data would be preferred (just as the original code works for single filter), however needing to launch a VBA script via button after the cell has been adjusted is the 2nd best option.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can include a pretty large number of Ranges all in the same set of code if you change around the way that you're checking whether the target intersects with x range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets(1).Range("I6:I7")) Is Nothing Then

        '<previous code>

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Worksheets(1).Range("H6")) Is Nothing Then

        '<new code>

    End If

End Sub
```